# spark parquet partitioning which remove the partition column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

If am using `df.write.partitionby(col1).parquet(path)`  .

the data will remove the partition column on the data.
how to avoid it ?

Comment: just curios why would you need that. One way if you want that column you can decide not to partition the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate `col1` before writing:

```
df.withColumn("partition_col", col("col1")).write.partitionBy("partition_col").parquet(path)
```

Note that this step is not really necessary, because whenever you read a Parquet file in a partitioned directory structure, Spark will automatically add that as a new column to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Actually spark does not remove the column but it uses that column in a way to organize the files so that when you read the files it adds that as a column and display that to you in a table format. If you check the schema of the table or the schema of the dataframe you would still see that as a column in the table.

Also you are partitioning your data so you know how that data from table is queried frequently and based on that information you might have decided to partition the data so that your reads becomes faster and more efficient.